# Is it possible that atoms in a crystal emit radiation (lose some) and absorb radiation from neighboring atoms?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics

I was just studying condensed matter theory and in particular was examining models for crystal solids. I found that an introductory classical model used is the one of coupled harmonic oscillators. One could also add one anharmonic term to it and model the same type of solids (In fact this is called the Fermi-Pasta-Ulam (FPU) problem). If furthermore, the system is isolated I was thinking that one may add to this model dampening and a driven periodic force.

The physical reasoning behind this is the fact that an isolated crystal solid (any material) radiates energy, but not all energy is lost, part of it could be reabsorbed. (I think this process could be modeled with dampening and a driven force). Then the model would be coupled anharmonic oscillators with dampening and a periodic driving force.

Now, it would seem to me that this type of system in which electromagnetic radiation is emitted and absorbed could be used, since the system may be more realistic described, but more importantly since this will allow the description of the system out of the equilibrium. Since this system is chaotic (and possibly ergodic). If ergodic, after long periods of times the system will reach thermal equilibrium and maximize entropy (This did not happen with the FPU problem). If you know of any references where I could read more about models of solids in condensed matter theory please let me know. Otherwise I would like to know if you think the model proposed above seems plausible and if you know if something similar had been proposed